# Plural “who clause” subtlety

Tags: clauses

“Most Americans who have a car…”

“Most Americans who have a car in *their garage*…”

Should that be *his garage*? *Their garages*?

“Most Americans who have cars in their garages…” sounds unobjectionable, but what if I’m trying to emphasize that there is only one car in each garage?

I’m sure that in real life I would say “Most Americans who have one car in their garage,” but I strongly suspect that (before the era of arbitrary gender pronouns) this is not quite grammatical.

I think the answer is clearer if we change “Most Americans” to “Each American.”

Any assistance is very appreciated, especially if it includes a reference.

Comment: Yes, you could write about each American with a car in the garage. But *Most Americans who have a car in their garage…* sounds natural, too.

Comment: For precision, do use "one," or "exactly one."